# this keyword result undefined in ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, perfect-scrollbar

I have this strange problem: I have a page that works fine on all major browser except IE11, where the page doesn't load.

I checked in the console in ie 11 and found this error:

[image]

the error refers to the function SetStyle, that set the style of the scroll bar:

```
class ScrollBarStyle{
  init(){
    return{
      setStyle: this._setStyle
    }
  }
  _setStyle(node,color,targetClass){
    let self = this;
    let children = Array.from(node.children); // I have set Array.from polifyll for ie11
    if(children){
      children.forEach(function(el){
        if(el.classList.contains(targetClass)){
            el.style.width = '10px';
            el.style.background = color;
            el.style.opacity = '1'
            return
        }
        self.setStyle(el,color,targetClass)
        })      
      }
    }
  }
```

this is a function I use to set the style of scrollbar in this way:

```
  _initMainScrollBar(){
    let self = this;
    this.contents.forEach(function(cnt){
      let ps = self.createScrollBar(cnt); //using perfect scrollbar plugin
      let color = self._RetrieveScrollBarColor(cnt)[0]; // get the main color of a section
      self.scrollBarStyle.setStyle(cnt,color,self.targetClass) //set the style
    })
  }
```

I dont know what's could be the problem, this code works in other browser and I have not found useful information about ie11 and `this` keyword.

Apparently seems that doing `var n=this` n results to be undefined,

Honestly I have no clue of what could be the problem.

I'm using babel with gulp:

```
gulp.task('js',()=>{
  return browserify({
    entries: ['./src/js/main.js'],
    debug:true
   })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(babel({
    presets: ['env'],
    compact: true
  }))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/dist/js/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

And also I have inserted the `Array.from` polyfill for ie11, so I don't think is that the problem

Someone can give me some hints about this problem? maybe is something related to perfect-scrollbar plugin?

Comment: I'd be surprised if IE11 supported `classList.contains`.

Comment: It does, check the MDN refs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Indeed, but there's caveats: https://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Comment: yes but they don't concern the contains method

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't say what the error is. Calling `var n = this;` would not result in an error in any browser that I know of.